# Overflow hidden seems to add padding to paragraph element

Tags: css, overflow

I can't figure out what is causing this. As you can see in [here (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/stsrjnxk/15/) when I add overflow:hidden (or display:inline-block or float:left)it seems it add top and bottom padding to paragraph moving in down. Can someone explain please what is causing this?

```css
.container{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.problem{
    background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    font-size: 120%;
    color:white;
    margin-top: 55%;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="problem"><p>text</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you are seeing the effects of collapsing margins and block formatting contexts.

When you add the `overflow: hidden` property to `.problem`, the element establishes a new block formatting context.

As a result, the default margins of the child `p` element are constrained within
the edges of the parent element.

Without the `overflow: hidden` property, the margins of the `p` element collapse
with the 55% margin of the parent block.

For more information about block formatting contexts, see the CSS2 specification at:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

Comment: Making `.problem` an inline-block or floating it, as mentioned in the question, both have the same effect described here. In other words, the explanation is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have some CSS automatically included.

Add this to clear the default paragraph margins:

```
p { margin:0px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stsrjnxk/16/

For more information Google:  CSS Reset

Comment: Thanks for answering I was using css reset, but i have it imported as second css style... now i found out it doesn't work this way :)